# Optimize table for queries that filter by date & hour?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

We have a historical table that stores hourly data. Currently, the table has 80 million rows and only has YTD data from this year. The data is stored in this format when the import's done.

The table schema looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ElectricFaults](
    [ElectricFaultsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeDt] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Street] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StreetSector] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [FaultValue] [smallint] NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

The table has two nonclustered index: one with `ElectricFaultsId` and the other with `DateTimeDt`. I haven't added a primary key yet.

I'll be grouping by month, and the grouping will be determined by data from this query:

```
select *
From 
ElectricFaults pm inner join DimStreetSectors dim on
RIGHT(StreetSector, LEN(StreetSector)-5) = dim.StreetSector
where 
pm.DateTimeDt >= dim.AddedDate
and cast(pm.[datetimedt] as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-11-25'
and ((datepart(hh, pm.datetimedt) between 20 and 23) or (datepart(hh, pm.datetimedt) between 0 and 4))
and FaultValue>= 30 --30 mins
```

Currently, the result is displayed in 14-15 seconds and returns 54K rows.

What would I do to optimize this query? Without the `inner join` it takes over a minute to execute completely and returns over 1M rows.

I was considering removing the `RIGHT` by adding an additional column that includes `RIGHT(StreetSector, LEN(StreetSector)-5)`. I was also considering including an `hour` column since I filter throgh that.

Comment: To prevent the table from being a heap, I would add the ElectricFaultsId as a primary key to speed inserts and deletions, however, it will not help the query above. Any function you place in a join or in a where clause will likely negate the use of indexes using the encapsulated fields.

Comment: No need for a column for the `date` data type; use proper date logic: `DateColumn >= '20190101' AND Datecolumn < '20191126'`. `BETWEEN` is a terrible operator to use when dealing with dates that have a time component.

Comment: You aren't doing yourself any performance favors by not having at least a clustered index in your table. You have what is called a heap and they are kind of nasty things. You also have nonSARGable predicates all through your join and your where clause. Computed persistent columns as mentioned would help. Might also consider adding an index to them. Yes you can index a persisted computed column.

Comment: @RossBush a PK won't prevent the table from being a heap, a clustered index is needed for that.

Comment: @alroc - You are correct, that was a short-circuit on my part. Almost all of my PK's are clustered, however, there is no requirement that a PK be clustered or that a clustered index be unique.

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating a computed column on your table [dbo].[ElectricFaults], for RIGHT(StreetSector, LEN(StreetSector)-5).

(You can read about some caveats about computed column - http://www.sqlservice.se/sql-server-performance-death-by-computed-column/)

Answer (score 0):

To address join it is a good idea to go with **your considered option** (having an actual column on RIGHT(StreetSector, LEN(StreetSector)-5) or go with a computed column as *@dataconsumer* suggests. This will save you some computation (CPU time), but you still need to scan table for join.

To address date is is fine to go with @Larnu option (pay attention - the last date is your day +1 day to include all hours)
to address the hour part I would go by creating computed/persisted columns for 
(datepart(hh, pm.datetimedt) between 20 and 23) let's name it hours4TillMiddnight bit,

and for 
(datepart(hh, pm.datetimedt) between 0 and 4)) let's name it hours4AfterMiddnight bit and then have them populated.

if you have any other time segments you can do it in same way

Also, make table clustered and consider to move old data to storage. Clustering in your case can totally make sense doing on the date, street not on Id.